# Can't get syntax highlighting to work in "Ace" text editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I recently used Ace in a project for my employer, but now I've moved on and I can't seem to get syntax highlighting to work on my new project.  Please note that I no longer have access to the old project that I used Ace on.

I copied the code into my site from http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding where it explains how to embed Ace into a web page.

I noticed that in the example, the ace.js file from the src-noconflict directory in ace-builds is used, so I downloaded that specific file from github (latest version as of 10 minutes ago).

I copied that ace.js file into my new project.

When I try to launch the web page in IE, I see the following error message:

Line: 13096
Error: Unable to get property 'cssClass' of undefined or null reference

Once I dismiss the error message, it appears that the Ace editor works on the page, but everything is black and white - no syntax highlighting.

What could I be doing wrong and what can I do to get Ace working properly?

Comment: If you are using the embed snippet, you are also using ``setTheme`` and ``setMode`` which require the monokai and mode-javascript files to be in the directory where your ace.js file resides.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  Why don't you post this as the answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: great, glad to hear it worked. I've moved my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the embed snippet, you are also using `setTheme` and `setMode` which require the `monokai` and `mode-javascript` files to be in the directory where your ace.js file resides.